# Scrapy Deployment Algorithm

Tags: python, mysql, cron, scrapy, scrapyd

Please help me clear my head a little bit:

I want to setup a crawl for my project on EC2. I'm using Scrapy with MySQL for results. Plus I want to implement cron for scheduled crawls (e.g. everyday); so my understanding is: I set up EC2 with all necessary packages(python, mysql, scrapy, etc.); then I create my spiders, I test them; and when they work I set up cron for crawls to happen without me.

Am I right or I might be missing something? Do I need to use Scrapyd or it's just an option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a program that will run Scrapy for you. You can use `scrapy` command or write your own script or you can use scrapyd. I personally like scrapyd since it makes things easier (including a nice [API](http://scrapyd.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html)).

Comment: okay, so I actually need to use Scrapyd if I want to set it up to run without me?

Comment: Basically, I just do what I explained I was going to do, but after I test my spiders I run my spiders using Scrapyd and then I use cron to automate Scrapyd? I haven't seen Scrapyd providing an automated crawling (e.g. every hour) in its documentation or am I missing something there?

Comment: You don't need scrapyd actually. You can just schedule `scrapy crawl <spider>`. But scrapyd can help with other features like API and web monitoring. If you choose scrapyd, you will need to start the crawl using the API (perhaps using `curl`).

Comment: If the answer was helpful, please upvote it and accept it as the answer.

Comment: accepted it right away but can't up vote since not enough rating